# What is the request url for a Meetup.com API to find all events in a particular city (entered by user) within a certain id?

Tags: httpresponse, api-design

I'm new to APIs but managed to get a few standard Meetup.com API responses to work in my Rails app; now I need to customise. I've read through all the documentation, and I can't manage to find the right response url to suit my needs. I want the user to be able to search their city (or within 30 mile radius of their city) for events organised by a particular member. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get events organized by a specific member and then filter manually, since a given member probably doesn't organize that many events? Or is the problem getting all events organized by a given member?

Answer (score 1):

I only had a quick glance at the Meetup API docs, but it didn't appear to provide this functionality. You will therefore need to get more data and filter out the ones you don't want - probably want a cache of some sorts to avoid hitting their API too hard.

Using the [GET /find/events](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/find/events/) end-point you can get events by lat/lng. In the response there is a collection `event_hosts`, you would then use this data to remove events not organised by the particular member(s) you are looking for.

Hope that helps

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, but will try your suggested work around. Thanks!